# Calling PyObject_CallMethod with a single tuple unpacks arguments?

Tags: python, cpython

Consider the following:

```
PyObject* fmt = PyUnicode_FromString("{0!r}");
PyObject* tup = PyTuple_New(2);
PyTuple_SetItem(tup, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("hello"));
PyTuple_SetItem(tup, 1, PyUnicode_FromString("world"));
PyObject* formatted = PyObject_CallMethod(fmt, "format", "O", tup);
PyObject* bytes = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(formatted, "UTF-8", "strict");
printf(PyBytes_AS_STRING(bytes));
```

I expect it to act like this python code:

```
>>> u'{0!r}'.format((u"hello", u"world"))
"(u'hello', u'world')"
```

However my output is simply:

```
u'hello'
```

I can imagine it is actually calling the function like:

```
>>> u'{0!r}'.format(u"hello", u"world")
u'hello'
```

What I'm looking for:

1. Why?
2. What is the minimal change can I get to have my expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the way `Py_BuildValue` works (which seems to be used by [`PyObject_CallMethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod)). From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue) (emphasis mine):

> Py_BuildValue() does not always build a tuple. It builds a tuple only
> if its format string contains two or more format units. If the format
> string is empty, it returns None; **if it contains exactly one format
> unit, it returns whatever object is described by that format unit.** To
> force it to return a tuple of size 0 or one, parenthesize the format
> string.

This means that instead of building the format string `"O"` with `tup` into `args=(tup,)` and calling `fmt.format(*args)` (expanding to `fmt.format(("hello", "world"))`), it builds `args=tup`, and so `fmt.format(*args)` expands to `fmt.format("hello", "world")`, as you thought. The solution is also in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue):

> To force it to return a tuple of size 0 or one, parenthesize the format
> string.

So, just change:

```
PyObject* formatted = PyObject_CallMethod(fmt, "format", "O", tup);
```

To:

```
PyObject* formatted = PyObject_CallMethod(fmt, "format", "(O)", tup);
```

And you get the desired output of `('hello', 'world')`. Full code snippet (compiled with `gcc thissnippet.c -I /usr/include/python3.4m/ -l python3.4m`):

```
#include <Python.h>
int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* fmt = PyUnicode_FromString("{0!r}");
    PyObject* tup = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(tup, 0, PyUnicode_FromString("hello"));
    PyTuple_SetItem(tup, 1, PyUnicode_FromString("world"));
    PyObject* formatted = PyObject_CallMethod(fmt, "format", "(O)", tup);
    PyObject* bytes = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(formatted, "UTF-8", "strict");
    printf(PyBytes_AS_STRING(bytes));
    Py_Finalize();
}
```